# Unit Testing Using embedded Cassandra in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, testing, junit, cassandra

I am trying to test a Spring Boot Application which includes saving into cassandra DB.
For unit testing I used EmbeddedCassandra.

These are the dependencies.

```
compile group: "com.datastax.cassandra", name: "cassandra-driver-core", version:"2.1.7"
    compile group: "com.datastax.cassandra", name: "cassandra-driver-dse", version:"2.1.7"
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile  ("org.cassandraunit:cassandra-unit-spring:2.1.9.2"){
        exclude group:"org.cassandraunit",module:"cassandra-unit"
    }
```

These are annotations I have used

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = MyController.class)
@Import(value = {MyDao.class})
@ContextConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = {
        CassandraUnitDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        CassandraUnitTestExecutionListener.class,
        ServletTestExecutionListener.class,
        DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class}
)
@EmbeddedCassandra(timeout = 60000)
@CassandraDataSet(keyspace = "test", value = {"test.cql"})
```

But the values saved in unit testing is populated original cassandra db .
Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra unit uses:
native_transport_port: 9142, but spring boot expects  9042 port, so you should change a port in your configuration or use your cassandra.yaml file. 
As an alternative you can take a look at this one:

https://github.com/nosan/embedded-cassandra/blob/master/README.adoc#spring-boot

It also provides @Cql annotation to execute cql scripts before or/and after each test.

Hope, it would be useful for you.

Comment: I tried this.Still its raising the error , showing the Keyspace 'realkeyspace' does not exist.Its the actual keyspace.

Comment: You have used  @CassandraDataSet(keyspace = "test",..),  can you change 'test' on 'realkeyspace'?